# Jquery Datatables.net : After sorting the table, odd times, the listeners don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm working with tables from datatables.net and i have an issue, very tricky to solve and i need ideas from everybody. So this is my table 
[image]

I apply an event handler to every checkbox that i have in every row
my event handler is

```
function checkListagem() {
        $('input:checkbox.checkboxinput').on('click',function (e) {
            this.checked ? listagensParaCartas.push($(this).attr('id')) : listagensParaCartas.pop($(this).attr('id'));
            var tem = $(this).parents("tr").hasClass("selecionada");
            if (!tem) {
                $(this).parents("tr").addClass("selecionada");
            }
            else {
                $(this).parents("tr").removeClass("selecionada");
            }
        });
    }
```

i also tried

```
$('"#listagens input:checkbox').on('click','.checkboxinput', function (e)
```

where listagens is the id of the datatable. When i click in the checkbox this aplly the name class "selecionada". example in this case i have

```
<tr class="odd selecionada>...</tr>
<tr class="even>...</tr>
<tr class="odd>...</tr>
```

but when i sort by the columns "Listagem" "Data Criação" or orther, they dont always apply the class to that tr. but is i replace for example this

```
 $(this).parents("tr").addClass("selecionada");
```

for this

```
 $(this).parents("tr").css("color","red");
```

the event handler works with the css but not with the addclass, or removeClass.
BUT if i click again sometimes work, sometimes dont. i think if i click sorting even times in the same column it goes back to work right, but when is odd times, does apply the class.

For now i'm going to disable the sorting, more important is having the selected, or in portuguese "selecionada", but i really need some really good idea. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try using `$('#listagens').on('click','.checkboxinput', function (e)`

Comment: For your information, that's called [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation).

Comment: Not working @NielsNet but thanks. i had tried that before also.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle with your problem